# Calculate variable depending on column specification

Tags: r

I have a data set containing eye tracking data looking similar to this dummy.df

```
dummy.df <- data.frame(GY = sample(300:600, 500, replace = T), 
                   target.position = sample(c("up", "down"), 500, replace = T),
                   trial.number = rep(1:10, each = 50))
toptargetpos_px <- 550
bottomtargetpos_px <- 350
```

GY is the position data of the eye on the Y-axis. 
toptargetpos and bottomtargetpos represent a horizontal line on the Y axis that the eye has to cross. 
I would like to mutate an extra column which specifies per target.position if the horizontal line is crossed.

So what is can do is:

```
dummy.df %>%
  mutate(on.target = GY >= toptargetpos_px)
```

This gives TRUE if GY is indeed above toptargetpos_px. However, i want the script to take into account what the target.position is (up or down), so it takes the corresponding horizontal line (toptargetpos_px or bottomtarget_px)

Which would look something like this:

```
dummy.df %>%
  mutate(on.target = GY[target.position == "up"] >= toptargetpos_px) | 
                     GY[target.position == "down" <= bottomtargetpos_px]
```

However, this is not working. What can i do to make it work ? I can ofcourse make 2 columns, but this is not ideal.

Comment: Do you mean this: `dummy.df %>%
  mutate(on.target = (target.position == "up" & GY >= toptargetpos_px) | 
                      (target.position == "down" & GY <= bottomtargetpos_px))` ?

Comment: ahh yes! Couldnt get it right! thanks @AntoniosK!

Comment: @AntoniosK Any suggestion on how to adapt the code if i want to add an error range to bottomtargetpos and toptargetpos? for instance 5 and -5? I tried >= (toptargetpos + c(5,-5)) but doesnt do the job

Comment: Maybe you can add the error and update that column and then use it like before. Unless you want to use `>= max(toptargetpos + c(5,-5))` and `<= min(bottomtargetpos + c(5,-5))`. But this is just considering `5` always for `toptargetpos` and `-5` for `bottomtargetpos`. In other words, when you have a range of values you want to check if your new value is bigger than the biggest range value or smaller than the smallest range value.

Comment: @AntoniosK Great. Got if figured out.